# images uploaded to aws, but can't be viewed in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have just integrated AWS with my rails/heroku app and I am using paperclip. I am able to upload files (photo's) and see them in AWS, however they are not showing up in the view. I am not getting any errors, and have not found a working solution in other posts.

It seems I am able to view the image in a browser, and that permissions are set to public:[image]

I suspect that I may have my region wrong, in the url of my aws dashboard the region says `region=us-west-2` yet googling and reading through other forums and posts on SO leads me to believe that if I am in the US my region should be set to `us-east-1` - currently I have it set to the latter. Not sure if this is the problem.

Here is a link to the image on AWS:https://s3.amazonaws.com/giving-tree-images/avatars/1/medium/02108_navajoland_1440x900.jpg

here is the code pertaining to aws/paperclip in my model:

```
:storage => :s3,
# :s3_host_name => "s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
},

:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
:default_url => "default_img.png"
```

and I am displaying in the view like this:

`<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:medium) %>`

I would love it if someone could point me in the right direction... Any additional info needed, please let me know!

Comment: S3 does not require region check this drop down from AWS console http://imgur.com/a/xY4ax

Comment: Why is the folder structure different ? image link has "/avatars/1/medium" directories in it but you screenshot just has "giving-tree-images"?

Comment: interestingly, they were uploading to aws just in the bucket's root. on my last upload, a folder called 'avatar' was created. the code above was actually slightly different then what i was originally specifying as the path - which was `:path => ":filename.:extension"` ... with the new folder created that path correctly references the images in them, they are just not displaying

Comment: I am updating my question with the most current upload, so the new path is displayed

Comment: Make sure your API keys are valid and enable on aws security credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, so this is how I solved it:

1. Create a new initializer file i.e. config/initializers/paperclip.rb
2. Add following in this file
   `Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url' 
   Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'`

To get details about your region, go to aws

[Amazon Web Service - Check your host name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK1Hg.jpg)

Note : Replace `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com` with your own host name

Reference : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Comment: I had to do this, too. (my region also = us-west-2 )  There's an issue in paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2309

Answer (score -1):

Have you enable the read permission to everyone?
It gave me access-denied error when accessed to the link.

Comment: actually just prior to reading you comment I had someone else open it in their computer and they were able to view it, yet after reading your answer i double checked the permissions- and they were not set to 'everyone/view', so i just enabled that,  but the image is still not showing up.

Comment: can you see it now?

Comment: Yes, i can see it now using this link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/giving-tree-images/meditation.jpg.jpg
The name has double `jpg` so may be it's problem.

Comment: awesome. well it still isnt showing up in the view - but that is a start

Comment: i just noticed your comment about the double jpeg, good eye. However that does not seem to be the issue as I also cannot see this image in my view, which does not have a double file extension https://s3.amazonaws.com/giving-tree-images/avatars/1/thumb/02108_navajoland_1440x900.jpg :(